# htaccess - rewrite url from /test to index.php?page=test

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite URLs using htaccess. The idea behind this is quite simple:

> Once a visitor visits `https://example.com/pineapples`, the browser should load `https://example.com/index.php?page=pineapples` instead while remaining the original URL.

This should only happen when a file exists in `/pages/` with the name of the requested URL, in this case `pineapples.php`.

This also counts for subdirectories: `https://example.com/pineapples/flamingos` should redirect to `https://example.com/index.php?page=pineapples/flamingos` when the file exists in `/pages/`, in this case `/pages/pineapples/flamingos.php`, where `pineapples` is a subdirectory.

Now I've tried to do this, but it's very buggy. It doesn't work for subdirectories as explained above, and it seems to work for all the directories, instead of just `/pages/`.

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif|svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages(/|$)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/). /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If someone please can help me out get this to work, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered using the following htaccess.

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif|svg)$
RewriteRule ^(ajax|assets|auth)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't check `REQUEST_FILENAME` because in your case it has to be in `pages`

so you may want to try

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteLog /path/to/log
RewriteLogLevel 5

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|png|gif|svg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages(/|$)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[^/]+/). /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}pages%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also I have enabled rewrite log, so in case it doesn't work, please post the logs your get

Comment: Hi Turan, thanks for your input. Unfortunately this does not seem to solve the problem. When I go to `/test`, while a file called `test.php` exists in `/pages`, it shows a 404 page, while my original script didn't do this.

Comment: @AppelFlap, yes seems I made a mistake because `/pages` was not supposed to be part of the url. I have updated the config, see if this one works. Also if not please post the logs